# How to get inode count of a filesystem on Solaris/Unix?

Tags: c, unix, solaris, inode

I was invoking the following command and reading the outpup `df -F ufs -o i`. It worked fine initially but then started to fail for the reason reported and explained here http://wesunsolve.net/bugid/id/6795242.

Although the solution suggested on the above link might work but it is ugly and I want a permanent solution. So, really looking for c api on Solaris/Unix that would give me the total and available number of inodes given a filesystem.

Sample/Example is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [statvfs](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/statvfs.html) system call can be used to retrieve file system statistics including the number of total inodes and the number of free inodes. Use the system call to retrieve a [statvfs](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/statvfs.h.html) structure and then inspect the `f_files` and `f_ffree` fields to determine the number of inodes and the number of free inodes, respectively.

Example:

```
#include <statvfs.h>

struct statvfs buffer;
int            status;
fsfilcnt_t     total_inodes;
fsfilcnt_t     free_inodes;
...
status = statvfs("/home/betaylor/file_in_filesystem", &buffer);

total_inodes = buffer.f_files;
free_inodes  = buffer.f_ffree;
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer and write an example :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `statvfs` -- see the [man page on the Solaris web site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19109-01/tsolaris8/816-1056/6m7gi1i52/index.html).